# Whether it works on flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I a new to flask,python programming. I want to know whether this problem can be solved :

let say I want to known whether a number is prime or not. 
I have created a html webpage,it contain a textbox and a button field respectively.
The user will give input from the html page as a front end. In the back end the flask will give the response that the number is prime or not. In the back end my python script has a function name prime which will decide the number is prime or not. 
The result  will be displayed back in the html page.

If this is possible please tell how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You should proceed by actually trying to write such an application (perhaps looking at the [Flask documentation and tutorials](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/)), and then if you run into any particular problem, asking more specific questions about particular problems you run into along the way.